# Retrieve value from XML directly

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I want to know if it is possible to extract and element from a XML in the following fashion. I have tried multiple options such as LinqToXMl and XPath.

```
<Paper>
  <HeaderText>
     StackOverFlow
  </HeaderText>
</Paper>
```

For the above XML, if my input is "HeaderText" (the element to be retrieved).
How can I do that without accessing the root element?

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XPath has a double-slash which looks anywhere:

```
//HeaderText/text()
```

That will return `Stack Overflow`.

Comment: XPath engine will still walk the root element... Not sure what OP mean "without accessing root element".

Comment: I figure it just meant that whatever query they were going to use can't include the word `Paper` for some reason.

Comment: @Joe : Thats is correct, I cannot use the word "Paper" Your comment reagrding "double-slash" guided me in the right direction. Thank You.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : I wanted to access all the elements in an xml without looping or querying it

Comment: @Richard - please edit your question with this requirement to clarify what you are looking for. Consider accepting this answer as it provides all necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to get this working.

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(requestXmlString);
XmlNodeList nodes = document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//HeaderText");
```